# How can I permanently setting the Screen Layout (arandr) in Manjaro i3?

Tags: x11, xorg, manjaro, i3

I recently installed Manjaro i3 on my laptop and tried to connect an external Monitor, to extend the main Screen when it's plugged in and just use the single monitor mode when not.

This seems to mostly work using arandr. Unfortunately I have to reapply the arandr settings again on every boot to get my layout back, since it gets reset every time.

I have tried exporting the arandr commands to .xinitrc and /root/xinitrc, I have tried editing the xorg confs and I have tried putting it into .screenlayout, but with no result.

So how can I permanently set my screen resolution and layout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I case somebody comes across this question:
 1. open arandr
 2. Set your desired layout
 3. Export it
 4.  open /etc/lightdm/xsession
 5. Add the exported code before the last line
 6. reboot

Comment: quick addition: if you want to automatically switch between layouts if you plug and unplug a screen to a laptop, check out autorandr